# Android Menu title element

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner, android-xml, android-menu

In Android xml, I know that a menu can be defined as:

```
<menu />
```

It contains `<item />`s which contain drawables, titles and IDs. Sometimes, the items contain sub `<menu />` tags. How is it possible to add a title to the entire `<menu />` element such as in this picture?

[image: Android Menu XML with title]

Also, how can the title of the menu be colored as it is in this picture? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try with a [ListPopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListPopupWindow.html). I guess that could works.

You have to implement a custom adapter that will have the behavior you describe.
Then :

```
YourCustomAdapter yca = new YourCustomAdapter();

ListPopupWindow popupWindow = new ListPopupWindow(context);
popupWindow.setAdapter(new YourCustomAdapter());
popupWindow.setWidth(300);      // Prefer using DPI scaling.
popupWindow.setAnchorView(yourView);
```

*Tip: If you can, use the support library version of ListPopupWindow.*